# How can I display an image from a url being imported from a csv file

Tags: php, html

```
<?php foreach ($output as $row): ?>
       <tr>
         <td><?=$row[25]?></td>
       </tr>
```

Row 25 contains text urls from imported csv file. Would like to know if there's a way to display the image of the url instead. All images are on the same server.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/wiki/Html/Elements/img

Comment: foreach ($output) will print every `row` of the array instead of just `row 25`

Comment: Do you mean row25 or column 25 ?

Comment: Yes, it will be displayed in a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to dislpay an image on a web page, and you've got a valid URL for it, then use a standard `<img` tag like you would in any HTML document.

e.g. in your case it would likely be something like this:

```
<td><img src="<?=$row[25]?>" /></td>
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Comment: Yes, that was one of the first things I tried, but I just get the broken link image icon.

Comment: Well that doesn't necessarily mean it was the wrong code to use, it might just mean the URL isn't valid, or can't be loaded in your page for some reason. Did you try to debug that at all? Use your browser's Developer Tools to a) check the final rendered HTML in the page and check that the URL is present in the "src" tag and contains what you expected, and b) check the Network tab when the page is loading, to see the request going to the image URL to see whether it succeeds or not, and c) check the Console for any errors or warnings which might be relevant.

Comment: I apologize, I did originally look at the source code in the Developer tools, everything seemed ok. But then I hovered over the link, and I noticed it was showing a double domain name. I moved the file to the root folder and removed the domain name in the csv file, and it works! Thanks so much.